# Rails 5.2 ActiveRecord query returns array instead of ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I see that performing a .first() or .last() query on an ActiveRecord query returns an array instead of an ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation. This prevents me from appending an .order() clause as that is not an array method.

Stepping back to the goal for a minute, I want to pull the latest five ("live", ie. active) comments related to a post and this is the code that fails:

```
@post.comments.where(status: "live").last(5).order(id: :desc)
```

The error is

> undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x00000011b096c0>

If I remove the .last() clause, or the .order() clause I get a valid result but obviously not the result set that I am angling for.

What's the best way to get the last five live comments in reverse chronological order? More importantly, perhaps, where is the best documentation / tutorial on this syntax? I find [the official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) too brief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking about documentation, I could recommend [Rails API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html). It has a lot of detailed descriptions for each interface method.

What about your question, you could use `limit` method instead of `first` or `last`:

```
@post.comments.where(status: "live").limit(5).order(id: :desc)
```

It does not affect the type of result (it stays `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`). Hence, if no result is found, this relation with `to_a` method will be converted to an empty array. This is different from the behavior of `first` and `last` methods which return `nil` in case of no result.

Comment: I just realized that `limit` (as you point out) returns an `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` where `take` returns an `array`. So, yours is the (much) better answer!

Comment: Thanks, both of you. Ilya - well done answering both questions :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
@post.comments.where(status: 'live').order(created_at: :desc).take(5)
```

I just plugged in `created_at`. Maybe you'll want `updated_at` instead.